# how to make for loop in FindById and then send response in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose, server

Actually I want to receive all data after for loop is done in database. In the code, req.body is user's object id values. If server receives 3 id values, it will response 3 data to frontend. No call server 3 times. However, I don't know how to make response's array then send that array. I don't want to call server many times. plz help me.

```
exports.user_edit_mileage = (req, res ,next) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    for(let user of req.body){
    User.findById(user)
        .then(users=>{
            const response = {
                users: users.map(user =>{
                    return {
                        email: user.email,
                        password: user.password,
                        name: user.name,
                        mileage: user.mileage,
                    };
                })
            };
            res.status(200).json(response);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what babak has answered, but you'd need to select the fields to have the snippet do exactly what you want and omit any more fields in the user document.

```js
exports.user_edit_mileage = async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find({ _id: { $in: req.body } })
    .select({
      email: 1,
      password: 1,
      name: 1,
      mileage: 1
    });
  return res.send(users);
};
```

It's worth noting that you really should not send a `password` in a response ever, even though if it's hashed since it's a security threat.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
exports.user_edit_mileage = async(req, res ) =>{
   let users =  await User.find({_id: {$in: req.body}})
   return res.send(users)
}
```